# Using jQuery.support = false

Tags: jquery, browser-detection

So I recently wanted to use the jQuery to do some browser detection and noticed that the previous methods were currently deprecated as of jQuery 1.3.

They now recommend that instead of testing for a browser, test for the features of the browser. Sounds like a good idea, but I cant figure out how to actually utilize this idea.

```
$("p").html("This frame uses the W3C box model: <span>" +
            jQuery.support.boxModel + "</span>");
```

This is great and all, but how would I wrap that into something that was:

```
If jQuery.support.boxModel = false then
```

Any Ideas? Happy Holidays!

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to worry about box models any more. Use a Standards Mode DOCTYPE and IE6+ will give you the proper model. IE5 is dead and gone, thank heavens.

Comment: But there's inconsistent handling of dimensions when using padding isn't there? Or is that another issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(! jQuery.support.boxModel) {
    //do stuff
}
```